# Controlling Multiple Processes in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, so I have a bot hosting thing I do. It's pretty much the only thing I have right now that's keeping me sane. It's an IRC type bot for a music/chat website, and it does a lot of things. But the problem is keeping them online. I used to use a sh file that would start all the bots individually with [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever).

```
cd dir/bots
forever start bot1.js
forever start bot2.js
...
```

etc, etc. And that worked. But the bots themselves take around 30mb of RAM, while the forever process ALSO takes around 30mb of RAM. So with as many bots as I was running, I was near maxed out on RAM, and that wasn't good, because if I had to get another server, things would get infinitely more complicated for me, and if I'm being honest, I'm not very good at this.

So I did some research, and figured I'd just use `child.fork()` and use one bot.js to spawn the rest of the bots. And it works beautifully, and cut my ram useage down to less than half of what it was. But now it's a pain keeping the bots online.

```
var child = require("child_process");
var running = {};
var bots = ["bot1","bot2","bot3"];
for (var i=0;i<bots.length;i++) { 
    running[bots[i]] = child.fork("bots/"+bots[i]+".js");
};
```

My question is - is this the most efficient way to run this setup? Because they are constantly crashing, and if I want to be considered reliable by any means, they need to be pretty self sufficient, and just shutting off in the wee hours of the night whilst I'm sleeping.

Right now I am using [node-scheduler](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule) to create a fake cron job that sends a message to the bots (not a node message, because that would return as long as the js file is running, not if the bot is connected to the service) from the service, and have the bot return a command. And it sets a command, so that if it doesn't get a response from the bot in 15 seconds, it reboots it. But it doesn't seem to be working all the time. And I'm at a loss.

Any help would be appreciated, and I'll provide more details if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fleet](https://github.com/substack/fleet) by substack. A single fleet drone can manage as many processes as you want and will automatically restart any crashed processes.

Fleet works by setting up a hub and 1 or more drones connected to the hub. You use git to push your code to the hub. The hub automatically deploys the new version of your code to all the connected drones. Then you can call `fleet spawn -- node foo.js`. Fleet will start running `node foo.js` and will automatically restart foo.js if it crashes

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the use process `spawn` within node, use a `Promise` pattern to synchronize processes execution then join results with a `Promise.all` (see function `promiseAll` here:

```
var promiseAll = function(items, block, done, fail) {
    var self = this;
    var promises = [],
        index = 0;
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        promises.push(function(item, i) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                if (block) {
                    block.apply(this, [item, index, resolve, reject]);
                }
            });
        }(item, ++index))
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function AcceptHandler(results) {
        if (done) done(results);
    }, function ErrorHandler(error) {
        if (fail) fail(error);
    });
}; //promiseAll
```

Now do the import

```
var cp = require('child_process');
```

and write the execution block that will spawn each process:

```
var ExecutionBlock = function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
        var options = [
            "--ssl-protocol", "tlsv1",
            "--ignore-ssl-errors", "true"
        ];
        options.push(executableFile); // push input file path
        options.push(item); // push executable arguments
        // LP: now spawn the power!
        var child = spawn(settings.executable, options);
        // Listen for an exit event:
        child.on('exit', function(exitCode) {
            console.log("Child exited with code: " + exitCode);
            return resolve(exitCode);
        });
        // Listen for stdout data
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
        // child error
        child.stderr.on('data',
            function(data) {
                console.log('err data: ' + data);
                // on error, kill this child
                child.kill();
                return reject(new Error(data.toString()));
            }
        );

    } //ExecutionBlock
```

At this point, supposed to have in `inputItemsArray` the list of the arguments of our executable, we can run them through the `Promise.All` approach:

```
// inputItemsArray is a list of arguments for the executable
promiseAll(inputItemsArray, function(item, index, resolve, reject) {
    ExecutionBlock(item, index, resolve, reject);
}
,function(results) { // aggregated results

    // all execution done here. The process exitCodes will be returned
    // array index is the index of the processed that exited
}
,function(error) { // error

});
```

The completion block will aggregate exit codes in a array, since we have returned them in the `resolve`. In this way you can take a good control over the execution, having for each process the `exitCode`, eventual `stdout` and `stderr` for each of them, during the execution.

A working example in the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/8bbac67590f53c5bb66c754d8c73e19c).