# Is there a way to synchronously execute multiple JavaScript files in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So in Node I can execute a JavaScript file using a command like:

```
$ node src/someFile.js
```

But is there a way to execute *all* of the JavaScript files in a given directory synchronously (one file executes, then after it has finished the next one executes, etc)? Basically, is there a single command that would have the effect of something like

```
$ node src/firstFile.js
$ node src/secondFile.js
$ node src/thirdFile.js
...
```

I've tried commands like

```
$ node src/*.js
```

but with no success.

If there exists no such command, what's the best way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: Is an answer that uses shell-specific functionality acceptable to you? (I see you've already tried globbing)

Comment: @ￜＺＶￜ I'm currently running a Windows machine so shell scripting wouldn't be optimal for me personally - however if it does solve the issue then it should be a perfectly valid solution

Comment: I'll fixup my answer with a powershell result -- I think it would be best to do this from the shell unless you need to capture their exit code, restore their SEH chains in `CreateRemoteThread` etc.

Comment: I'm away from my windows machine, let me know if that PS script works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is going to work for you because this is a feature of the shell not of the node runtime but..

```sh
for f in src/*.js; do node "$f"; done
```

Or in Powershell:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem .\*.js | Foreach-Object {
  node $_ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use spawn to run a `node` process from node like

```
(function() {

var cp = require('child_process');
var childProcess = cp.spawn('node', [`src/firstFile.js`]);
```

At this point you have to add some listeners:

```
// now listens events
// Listen for an exit event:
child.on('exit', function(exitCode) {
    console.log("Child exited with code: " + exitCode);
    return resolve(exitCode);
});
// Listen for stdout data
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
// child error
child.stderr.on('data',
    function(data) {
        console.log('err data: ' + data);
        // on error, kill this child
        child.kill();
    }
);
}).call(this);
```

Of course you need to serialize execution here, but it's easy since you have the `child.on('exit')` that tells you that the process ended, so you can start the next one.

Look to [Controlling Multiple Processes in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867324/controlling-multiple-processes-in-node/36586245#36586245) for my example working solution that run multi processes in `node` and wait execution to end / join.

Comment: Ah so there's no simple one-liner solution native to node for this, but rather it requires writing a file (like you've suggested above)?

Comment: One line solution will not give you control of the process status, exit code, and the `pid`. Of course, you can write a `bash` script that takes the `pid`, execute `node $filename` in a for loop statement, etc, but you need a supervisor to handle all these processes, that can be writted in bash, python, perl or ...node.

Answer (score 1):

Using a POSIX shell:

```sh
$ for js in src/*.js; do node "$js"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If the calling each one from the shell thing isn't a hard requirement, I would kick them all off with a single node process from the shell. This node script would:

- traverse the directory of modules
- require the first one, which executes it, and pass a callback which the module will call on completion
- When the complete callback is called, execute the next script in your directory.